# how to know if the user's camera is broadcasting (he could have pressed deny instead of accept, or his camera might be turned off)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, camera

usually i do Camera.getCamera but when this method is called the user is prompted with a dialog box where he can choose to **allow or to deny the application access to the camera**, or he could **not have a camera**

how can the application now whether the camera is broadcasting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Camera class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera%28%29) documentation on LiveDocs says:

> Flash Player returns an information object in the status event that indicates the user's response: **Camera.muted indicates the user denied access to a camera; Camera.Unmuted indicates the user allowed access to a camera**. To determine whether the user has denied or allowed access to the camera without handling the status event, use the muted property.

Take a look at the [StatusEvent class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/StatusEvent.html) for more detail.